# VB.Net: LUIS Dialog context.Wait(MessageReceived) issue

Tags: vb.net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

As a challenge to myself, I've created a Visual Basic app that uses the Microsoft Bot Framework and LUIS API. To my own amusement, I've largely gotten it working .. almost.
After getting over some C# to VB hurdles, there's one I can't get over, which is stopping my app from keeping the conversation stack from functioning properly (it bails out after one interaction).
Specifically, I have the following code fragment inside of my dialog code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs
Imports Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis
Imports Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models

<LuisModel(“xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")>
<Serializable>
Public Class MyLuisDialog
    Inherits LuisDialog(Of Object)

    <LuisIntent("None")>
    Public Async Function NoneIntent(context As IDialogContext, result As LuisResult) As Task
        Await context.PostAsync(“this is boring chat ..“)
        context.Wait(MessageReceived)
    End Function
```

but I cannot interpret the context.wait(MessageReceived) from C# into VB.

The compiler wants to do:

```
context.wait(MessageReceived(context,????????))
```

but I cannot figure out what to put in for ?????.

Irritatingly, the C# version just works in the form context.wait(MessageReceived).

Assistance as to what syntax/code should be used when using VB gratefully accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `context.Wait(AddressOf MessageReceived)`

Comment: Genius! Thank you very much @Ezequiel Jadib. The dialog stack works as intended.